How do I remap compressed video to raw video in ROS2?
I have compressed video published by a rpi4 as /camera/image_raw/compressed
I want to republish it on my pc (ros2/Humble) in raw form as /image.
This works, but gives warnings:
ros2 run image_transport republish compressed in/compressed:=camera/image_raw/compressed raw out:=image
[WARN] [1714541064.983263144] [rcl]: Found remap rule 'in/compressed:=camera/image_raw/compressed'. This syntax is deprecated. Use '--ros-args --remap in/compressed:=camera/image_raw/compressed' instead.   
[WARN] [1714541064.983284740] [rcl]: Found remap rule 'out:=image'. This syntax is deprecated. Use '--ros-args --remap out:=image' instead.  

So I am trying to work out the new syntax.  I have tried all of the following:
ros2 run image_transport republish --ros-args --remap in/compressed:=camera/image_raw/compressed --remap out:=image
Usage: /opt/ros/humble/lib/image_transport/republish in_transport in:=<in_base_topic> [out_transport] out:=<out_base_topic>

ros2 run image_transport republish --ros-args --remap in/compressed:=camera/image_raw/compressed --remap out/raw:=image
Usage: /opt/ros/humble/lib/image_transport/republish in_transport in:=<in_base_topic> [out_transport] out:=<out_base_topic>

ros2 run image_transport republish --ros-args --remap in/compressed:=camera/image_raw/compressed  out/raw:=image
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rclcpp::exceptions::UnknownROSArgsError'
  what():  found unknown ROS arguments: 'out/raw:=image'
[ros2run]: Aborted

ros2 run image_transport republish --ros-args --remap in/compressed:=camera/image_raw/compressed  --ros-args --remap out/raw:=image
Usage: /opt/ros/humble/lib/image_transport/republish in_transport in:=<in_base_topic> [out_transport] out:=<out_base_topic>

What is the new syntax?

Finally hit on it!
To republish /camera/image_raw/compressed in raw form as /image:
ros2 run image_transport republish compressed raw --ros-args --remap in/compressed:=/camera/image_raw/compressed --remap out:=/image

The compressed and raw arguments need to go before --ros_args.  I have no idea why - there is nothing like this in the the documentation for using command line arguments.
My next issue was how to invoke republish from a launch file. I didn't bother asking a question in the forum because because this has proved to be fruitless.  If anybody needs to do it, the form is:
  <node name="image_republisher" pkg="image_transport" exec="republish"  output="screen" args="compressed raw">
    <remap from="in/compressed" to="/camera/image_raw/compressed"/>
    <remap from="out" to="/image"/>
  </node>

Note the args="compressed raw" part.
I struggled to invoke republish from a launch file because there are no examples in the documentation of how to pass parameters to a node apart from using the syntax  <param name="name" value="val"/>

Please don't ask follow up questions in the answer. This is a question about command line parsing. Launch syntax would justify a new question. I still make my question fully self-contained. But link to this version for more context in case people also have similar questions.

This is expected behavior. --ros-args collects all arguments after it until the next recognized option by the parser. Thus if you put those arguments after the --ros-args option parser is getting the strings instead of the top level argument parser.

Also please keep in mind that people here are volunteering their time to help you. And it takes time for the right person to see your question. The more concisely you can phrase your question and make minimal reproductions with simple components such as demo nodes the easier it will be to get a timely answer. As an example this question doesn't require any knowledge about compressed image transport, but based on the title many people not familiar with it will likely pass by the question because they assume they don't have the domain expertise.

@Tully The question is totally about compressed image transport!  I have been trying to convert compressed video from a rpi4 to raw video using ROS2 for nearly a week (it was easy in ROS1).  I can't find any documentation for the arguments taken by 'republish'.  You have spent a lot of time criticising the question and none trying to answer it.

@Tully I didn't ask a follow up question (as I mentioned, I didn't see much point).  I added information about how to invoke 'republish' from a launch file because the Humble documentation on launch files gives no clues as to how to pass arguments apart from using <param ...>

I sense that you're frustrated with the site. I'm trying to give you feedback on your questions that you've already self answered so that you can find this site more useful in the future. The best way to get a good answer to your question is to take the time to construct a well formed question. Improving your question will get you more help. You want to make it as easy as possible for someone in the community to be able to help you.
