Is this a bug in ros2 command line processing?
(This is similar to a previous question, but I have done more research and added new information)
I am trying to republish a compressed image topis as a raw topic using ROS2, Humble.
Firstly, this works (with warnings):
ros2 run image_transport republish compressed in/compressed:=camera/image_raw/compressed raw out:=image
[WARN] [1714586109.162818115] [rcl]: Found remap rule 'in/compressed:=camera/image_raw/compressed'. This syntax is deprecated. Use '--ros-args --remap in/compressed:=camera/image_raw/compressed' instead.   
[WARN] [1714586109.162842477] [rcl]: Found remap rule 'out:=image'. This syntax is deprecated. Use '--ros-args --remap out:=image' instead. 

So, I am trying to use the correct new syntax.  I can't find any decent documentation of republish for ROS2, but I found the source code.  This shows that republish:

Takes 2 parameters, in_transport and out_transport.
Uses topics in and out.

I also found documentation for command line syntax in Humble.
Putting this all together, the new syntax for invoking republish should be:
ros2 run image_transport republish --ros-args -p in_transport:=compressed -p out_transport:=raw -r in:=/camera/image_raw/compressed -r out:=/image
Usage: /opt/ros/humble/lib/image_transport/republish in_transport in:=<in_base_topic> [out_transport] out:=<out_base_topic>

...but it gives a usage error.
I am probably making a mistake somewhere, but I have been trying to get this to work for ages, and I can't see any error in my logic. Is there a bug?

add the information to the previous post and delete this one

If you think it warrants it's own follow-up you should always still link to the old question so others know about the related info. Looking at your profile to find https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/110939/how-do-i-remap-compressed-video-to-raw-video-in-ros2#110997 it's not different enough to warrant a separate question. It's the same question after you learned a partial solution.

I finally found syntax that works:
ros2 run image_transport republish compressed raw --ros-args --remap in/compressed:=/camera/image_raw/compressed --remap out:=/image

The compressed and raw arguments need to go before --ros_args.  I have no idea why - there is nothing like this in the the documentation for using command line arguments.  It seems impossible to pass the in_transport and out_transport parameters through the syntax explained in the documentation.
Conclusion:  I think there is a bug in the command line processing, or (possibly more likely) some kind of non-standard parameters required by republish.  Since I cannot find any documentation for this package in ros2, it is impossible to say.

This is expected behavior. --ros-args collects all arguments after it until the next recognized option by the parser. Thus if you put those arguments after the --ros-args option parser is getting the strings instead of the top level argument parser.

@Tully It isn't expected behaviour based on the documentation.  There is nothing about this in the link I gave.

The documentation you linked is about generic ROS command line arguments. The node command line arguments are not part of those and extends the parsing.  There's always space to improve the docs. Please consider suggesting a change in a pull request to improve it for future users who might hit the same point of confusion.
